# setting equal heights to columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter-bootstrap framework to create an 'article' with two columns. text on one side, and a column with a background image on the right.

HTML

```
<article>

 <div class='container-fluid'>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-8 indx-img" style="background-image:url('...');">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-8">

      <div class="text-cell">
        <h1>ttitle</h1>
        <h3>text</h3>
      </div>

    </div>

    </div><!-- /#row -->

  </div><!-- /#post -->

</article>
```

I want the article to have a responsive height. (a **%** or something) that shrinks as the screen size decreases. I need both columns to have the same height (the background-img one needs a height in order to display the background image)

My current css uses padding to generate a responsive size to the background-img column (**padding: 16% 0;**), but doesn't affect the left column ( I want the text vertically centered in its column)

I tried **height: 30%;** on article, but it does't add any height to the columns themselves.

Comment: can you reproduce your issue in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or post related css.

Comment: Unfortuntely I can't seem to figure out how to bring in bootstrap into js fiddle

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height

Answer (score 1):

Chris Coyier has a good solution for this already. I recommend reviewing this: https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

**Example from article:**

HTML

```
<div id="css-table">
  <div class="col"><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p></div>
  <div class="col"><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p></div>
  <div class="col"><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p></div>
  <div class="col"><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#css-table {
  display: table;
}
#css-table .col {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}
#css-table .col:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ccc;
}
#css-table .col:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}
```

Comment: Please don't just paste links here, you should add code with some explaination

Comment: @Tushar, according to the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) links are completely ok. It does not require code to accompany it. However, I will edit my answer and quote the relevant part of the article to improve the answer.

Comment: The layout uses columns made with tables, I'm using columns made with Bootstrap